# Issue when trying to set range values using ThisWorkbook when other sheet or workbook is selected

Tags: vba, excel

Why doesn't the code work when executing the macro if a different sheet or workbook is selected other than sheet1? I need the code in this format so I can change the values in the cell entries to variables later on. Is there any way to work around this?

```
Sub testhsa()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 2)).Value = 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work because you don't qualify the `Cells` component of the statement.

You need the following - notice the `.` before the `Cells`:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range(.Cells(1,1), .Cells(2, 2)).Value = 1
End With
```

Edit: Further clarification for the comment.
By leaving the `.` off a worksheet/range/cell, you are telling Excel you want the Active parent.  Ie `Cells(1, 1)` is the same `ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1)` and `Range("A1:D4")` is the same as `ActiveSheet.Range("A1:D4")`.

The `With` statement effectively tells Excel that anything that follows is associated 'with' that object so my 3 lines of code is exactly the same as:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2)).Value = 1
```

This clarifies to Excel that no matter what is the `ActiveWorkbook` you want the code access the range in the workbook the code is running from.

Finally, if you are using ranges often you'll want them assigned to a variable as HeadofCatering has rightly suggested.

Comment: +1 - this solves the problem. I've added an alternative with slightly different syntax.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks for helping a newbie get on the right track.

Comment: Just so I understand better, does the period before the cells enable the selection of those cells no matter what workbook or sheet you are in, just as the .Range object qualifies a range for selection within the workbook that the macro is running? In other words is it kind of like writing ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(values).Value, except that the cells are instead qualified within the range object?

Comment: No problems, I've edited my answer regarding your comment.  You should use it in addition to the nice extra bit from HeadofCatering

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend the use of variables for your objects. It makes it much easier to figure out what you're doing, and cleans up your code dramatically.

You can use the following code as a template:

```
Sub OperateOnInactiveSheet()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim writeThis as string

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(2, 2))
    writeThis = "foo"

    rng.Value = writeThis
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Head of Catering. This template will help me with some more difficult code I have to write.